# How would I show $|x| \le 1$ given the equation for $x$ the expression in the equation?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

The expression is $x = \sin(\theta /2)$. I am asking how would I show that $\sin(\theta/2)\le1$ based on the expression? I already know that the biggest $\sin$ will ever get is $[-1, 1]$ which is the period of the graph. So would I basically use the graph of $\sin(x)$? please help!

Comment: You already know that the "biggest sin will ever get is $[-1,1]$". The same is true for $\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$. So you already know that $|x|\le 1$. After all $|x|\le 1 $ means $-1\le x\le 1$.

Comment: So how would i show that?? would i use the half angle formula?

Comment: The $\frac{\theta}{2}$ is a red herring. The sine function maps *any* real value into the interval $[-1,1]$. So whatever the value of $\theta$, the value of $\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$ will be in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: That makes sense! so taking the absolute of the expression would mean that the values will always be less than one?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: Thank you! It makes so much sense! I guess i was over thinking it at first but now i know! :D that helps me out a lot

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "period of the graph"? You wouldn't really use the graph, but rather the basic trigonometric identity $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x) = 1$ or the very definition of sine.

Comment: Whoops i didn't mean to put that but hmm thats what i was also thinking but wouldn't i also use the half angle formula as well??